# Setting up PostgreSQL Connection with DBVisualiser

Tags: postgresql, connectivity

Apologies for the rudimentary question, I'm new to setting up databases. Am aiming to create a new Postgres connection and load some CSV files into a table using DBVisualiser. Working on a Mac running El Capitan 10.11.3

I enter all the details in the Connection Wizard as follows:

[image]

But get the following 5432 error when I try to ping the server.

[image]

Where am I going wrong? I also tried using `127.0.0.1` as my local host but that didn't work either.

Comment: http://www.dbvis.com/doc/8.0/doc/ug/getConnected/getConnected.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked your postgresql configuration, mainly the pg_hba.conf? Can you login to your server with psql? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: You should consider expanding your answer. As it is written it is more of a comment.

Comment: For some reason I don't have a pg_hba.conf file. I only have a pg_hba.conf.sample file. Presumable I need to edit the details in this file and save it as pg_hba.conf? Then do I leave it where it is or place it somewhere else?